# Sort filtered items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, filter

How can I sort filtered products? If I try to sort or filter products separately it works fine, but when filtering products and then trying to sort them, the filter/sort input resets without sorting the previously filtered products.

**products_controller.rb**

```
def index
  if params[:query].present?
    sql_query = "\
    name ILIKE :query\
    OR genre LIKE :query\
    "
    @pagy,@products = pagy(Product.where(sql_query, query: "%#{params[:query]}%"))
  else
    @pagy, @products = pagy(Product.all)
    @pagy, @products = pagy(@products.where(genre: params[:genre])) if params[:genre].present?
    @pagy, @products = pagy(@products.where(category: params[:category])) if params[:category].present?
    @pagy, @products = pagy(@products.where(brand: params[:brand])) if params[:brand].present?
  end
  if params[:sort_by]. present?
    sort_by = params[:sort_by]
    case sort_by
    when 'discount_product'
      @products = Product.where.not(discount: nil)
    when 'price_low_to_high'
      @products = @products.order(price: :asc)
    when 'price_high_to_low'
      @products = @products.order(price: :desc)
    when 'newest_arrivals'
      @products = Product.order(created_at: :desc).limit(15)
    else
      @products = @products.order(created_at: :desc)
    end
  end
end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<div class= "filter-by">
  <span>Filter by:</span>
  <%= form_tag products_path, method: :get do %>
    <%= select_tag :genre, options_for_select(["Men", "Women", "Kids"], params[:status]), prompt: "Gender" %>
    <%= select_tag :brand, options_for_select(["Adidas", "Nike", "Puma"], params[:brand]), prompt: "Brand" %>
    <%= select_tag :category, options_for_select(["Running", "Training", "Tennis"], params[:category]), prompt: "Type" %>
    <%= submit_tag "Filter" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
<div class="sort-by">
  <span>Sort by:</span>
  <%= form_tag products_path, method: :get do %>
    <%= select_tag :sort_by, options_for_select([
      ['Price: Low to High', 'price_low_to_high'],
      ['Price: High to Low', 'price_high_to_low'],
      ['Newest', 'newest']
    ], params[:sort_by]) %>
    <%= submit_tag 'Sort' %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Start by moving the filtering/sorting code out of the controller into a separate object.

```
# app/models/product_query.rb
# This is a model that is not saved in the database
class ProductQuery
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveModel::Attributes

  SORT_BY_OPTIONS = ['price_low_to_high', 'price_high_to_low', 'newest']
 
  attribute :name, :string
  attribute :genre, :string
  attribute :sort_by, :string, default: "newest"
  
  # @todo validate that the user input is valid for searching
  validates :sort_by,
   in: SORT_BY_OPTIONS,
   allow_blank: true


  def initialize(attributes = {})
    super(attributes)
  end

  # applies the filters and returns a new ActiveRecord::Relation
  def resolve(base_scope = Product.all)
    if valid?
      # @todo apply the filter / ordering to the the base scope
      base_scope
    else
      base_scope 
    end
  end
end
```

This avoids the fat controller anti-pattern and gives you an object that you can bind the parameters to and pass to a form builder:

```
class ProductsController
  def index
    @product_query = ProductQuery.new(product_query_params)
    @products = pagy(@product_query.resolve)
  end

  private

  def product_query_params
    params.permit(:sort_by, :gender, :brand, :category)
  end
end
```

```
<%= form_with(model: @product_query, url: products_path, method: :get, scope: nil) do |form| %>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Filter by:</legend>
    <div class="field">
      <!-- prompts or placeholders should not be used instead of labels -->
      <%= form.label :gender %> 
      <%= form.select :gender, ["Men", "Women", "Kids"] %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= form.label :brand %>
      <%= form.select :brand, ["Adidas", "Nike", "Puma"] %>
    </div>
    <!-- ... more fields -->
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Order by:</legend>
    <%= form.select :sort_by, [
      ['Price: Low to High', 'price_low_to_high'],
      ['Price: High to Low', 'price_high_to_low'],
      ['Newest', 'newest']
    ] %>
  </fieldset>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Just like when you're creating/updating your other models this form will retain the user input after submission. You don't actually need two separate forms.

Comment: Please note that this isn't a copy paste solution to your issue. It's a nudge in a better direction. I can't actually implement the search filters because what you have in the controller and in the form doesn't even make sense together. Why would you use `ILIKE` if the user is selecting a prefilled option and not entering a freetext for example?

Answer (score 0):

I'm also trying to figure out the best option for this, on a project I'm working on.

There are a few options I can think of.

1. Have the filter and sort fields inside the same form. This is probably the easiest, but it may not make sense if your filter and sort fields aren't close together on your page.
2. Save the filter and sort parameters in a session cookie.
3. Save just the sort parameters in a session cookie.
4. Whenever you change the filter or sort field update the action attribute for each form, using JS.

Note: I'm not sure option 4 will actually work, nor would it be a recommended way of solving this problem. I haven't seen this solution suggested anywhere, nor have I tried it yet.

For my project, I'm leaning more towards option 3.

https://www.colby.so/posts/filtering-tables-with-rails-and-hotwire has a good write-up about this problem.